# CheckBox Accessing a Database in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table called expertise, which contains the fields "code" and "description" .. There are about 20 rows in this table.

I want 20 checkboxes having the description from the expertise table so that the user can check as many checkboxes as they want to and once the submit the button, it must take "code" from the expertise table and post it to the database.

How can i do this ? can someone give me a step by step way to do this in MVC3

In my model, i have the following :

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be at least {2} characters long and a maximum of {1} characters with no spaces.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UserPhone")]
    public string userPhone { get; set; }


 public class ExpertiseModel
 {
     public string expertiseCode { get; set; }

     public string expertiseDesc { get; set; }
 }

 public class UserExpertiseModel
 {
     public string expertiseCode { get; set; }

     public string otherExpertise { get; set; }
 }


 public class RegisterSPModel
 {
     UserExpertiseModel userexpertisemodel;
     RegisterModel registermodel;

     public RegisterSPModel()
     {
         userexpertisemodel = new UserExpertiseModel();
         registermodel = new RegisterModel();
     }
 }
```

In my Controller i have :

```
    // GET: /Account/RegisterSP
    public ActionResult RegisterSP()
    {
        DBController dbcontroller = new DBController();

        if (dbcontroller.DBConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("view_all_expertise;", dbcontroller.conn);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("expertiseCode", MySqlDbType.String));
            command.Parameters["@expertiseCode"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("expertiseDesc", MySqlDbType.String));
            command.Parameters["@expertiseDesc"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            try
            {
                MySqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

                var expmodel = new ExpertiseModel();                  

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    expmodel.expertiseCode = rdr["expertiseCode"].ToString();
                    expmodel.expertiseDesc = rdr["expertiseDesc"].ToString();
                }

                ViewBag.Expertise = expmodel;
                return View();
            }
```

And in my VIEW i have this :
     @model mvc1.Models.RegisterSPModel

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RegisterSP";
 }

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

 <p>
     Use the form below to continue creating a new account. 
 </p>

 <div>
 <fieldset style = "width: 840px; margin:  0px auto;">
 <legend>Account Information - Service Provider</legend>
 <br />
      @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Expertise)
      {
          <div>
          <table>
          <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="codes"   value="@item.Expertise.expertiseDesc" />
          </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
      }
```

This doesnt work .. I am unable to get the RegisterSPModel data fields in the VIEW() even though i have it specified at the beginning of the VIEW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you have the following model:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourProject.Models.Expertise>
```

all you need to do is put your table in a `@html.beginForm` and add a `checkbox` to each row. and set the value of the `checkBox to "code"`

example:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
     @foreach (var x in Model)
        {        
          <div>
               <table>     
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="codes" value="@x.code"  /> 
                    </td>
                    ... // rest of your table
```

and then in your controller add a post method for the page:

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
 public ActionResult IndexPost(List<CTypeofCode>codes)
 {
   // codes is going to be the list of what the user selected.
   // now you are ready to do what ever you need to do with the users selection
 }
```